# Where is the official documentation for Mongoose save()?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Saving is probably one of the most common things you do with Mongoose.  However, I can not find the official documentation for the save method.  A [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=mongoose%20save&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS895US895&oq=mongoose%20save&aqs=chrome.0.69i59.6910j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) pulls up:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

and

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html

neither of which shows how to properly use the promise returned by save; however by trial I found out that it will give you the entire saved object as follows:

```
  Instance.save(obj).then((val) => {
    // val contains the object saved!
```

I want to know where the official documentations is that documents this behavior.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming it's this here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-save.

> If save is successful, the returned promise will fulfill with the document saved.

Comment: "If save is successful, the returned promise will fulfill with the document saved."